# XP SP3 -- and "Turn Off Computer" Looks Suspicious with my Neighbor's Name next to it

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I recently had Wi-Fi installed. Last week I logged off and I was shocked to find the following in the bottom left corner where the "Turn Off Computer" icon is located.   Instead of the normal icon it had `Turn Off ******`, where the asterisks denote my neighbor's first initial and last name.

What is this and is this neighbor stealing my Wi-Fi -- or in some fashion sharing my Wi-Fi?   It makes me suspicious.  Is this neighbor able to see what I am doing online and offline?

Comment: That's certainly very strange. I can't think of any reason why your computer would display your neighbor's name there. As far as wi-fi security, did you have any encryption (Such as WPA2) enabled so that a password is needed to connect to the access point?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "Turn of Computer" on your logon screen? This is taken from your computer description. Maybe somebody changed the description of this computer.

You can check (and change it back) by right-clicking "My computer" choosing `Properties` and then the tab `Computer Name`. There you see the `Computer Description`.
BTW: If you empty this field your old "Turn off Computer" comes back.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Makes me wonder if the neighbor was trying to let him know just how vulnerable his system was!

Comment: Or some buddy is playing a prank. But it's always good to make sure your WiFi is secure (and **check** this regularly, because somebody could have disabled this from within).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your machine attached itself to his WiFi. If you want to make sure he does not use your WiFi then use WPA2 security with a long strong composite password (containing letters, numbers, punctuation and spaces). WEP security is a very bad joke nowadays and is very easily cracked.